# How to set image and size of QListWidget in qt

Tags: c++, qt, background-image, qlistwidget

How to insert a background image in `QListWidget` and How to set the size of `QListWidget`?

```
QListWidget *list = new QListWidget();
list->addItem("Hello");
list->addItem("Hi");
```

Comment: Can you explain more precisely? Set image but not for an item, then where this image should be? Is your `QListWIdget` inside a layout?

Comment: In full QListWidget i want to set an image not to particular item.

Comment: I assume you are talking about a background image that the items in your list will be on top of.

Comment: I think you can use a style sheet for that.

Comment: Just give an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the background image through stylesheets using setStyleSheet.

```
list->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image_url.png)");
```

If you want it to be in the center, just add:

```
list->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image_url.png); background-position: center;");
```

If you want to set the size, you can do it through the stylesheet too as a fixed size:

```
list->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image_url.png); max-width:100px;min-width:100px; max-height:100px; min-height:100px;");
```

Setting max and min of them is the same as doing this by code:

```
list->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
list->setFixedSize(100,100);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
list->setStyleSheet(QString("QListWidget { background-image: url(imagename.png) }"));
```

See [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#background-prop).

Comment: Thank u bro and what about setting size of widget

Comment: Just learn to read documentation, check all base classes. Possibly learn to use layouts.

Comment: A faster answer should be better for him.